# Logstash casts log info into string

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I successfully started ELK with docker as described in [here](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk). then i implemented a test logger class to work with this stack as below:

```
import logging
from logstash_async.handler import AsynchronousLogstashHandler


class ELKLogger:
    def __init__(self, logger_name, host, port):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.logger.addHandler(
            AsynchronousLogstashHandler(host=host, port=port, database_path='logstash.db')
        )

    def info(self, message, **extra):
        self.logger.info(message, extra=extra)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random

    logger = ELKLogger('elk_logger', host='localhost', port=5000)
    logger.info('info test1', psuccessfull=True, pname='pname', prate=random.random())
```

code works fine and it sends my log data, but elk stores all my log inside a message attribute as string but i want to store it as object.

**Sample stored log:**

> {
>           "_index" : "logstash",
>           "_type" : "_doc",
>           "_id" : "3rDy72sBBPPgf4IYzCkZ",
>           "_score" : 1.0,
>           "_source" : {
>             "host" : "gateway",
>             "message" : """{"type": "python-logstash", "@timestamp": "2019-07-14T10:06:34.587Z", "extra": {"line": 14, "prate": 0.6982092931167561, "process_name": "MainProcess", "psuccessfull": true, "path": "main.py", "interpreter_version": "3.5.2", "pname": "pname", "logstash_async_version": "1.5.1", "interpreter": "/home/sina/Desktop/logstash-test/venv3.5/bin/python3", "func_name": "info", "logger_name": "python-logstash-logger", "thread_name": "MainThread"}, "level": "INFO", "program": "main.py", "pid": 28797, "logsource": "HS-Shaya", "message": "info test1", "host": "HS-Shaya", "@version": "1"}""",
>             "port" : 44780,
>             "@version" : "1",
>             "@timestamp" : "2019-07-14T10:06:34.924Z"
>           }
>         }

**ELK Version: 7.2.0**

Comment: I believe you have to edit the logstash.conf file under "pipeline" folder:  https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/blob/master/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf

Try parsing the message field with the json plugin in the filter block:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-source

Comment: @Chaooder yes that was it. thank you